# Где находиться связь Id и навигационного свойства в метаданных EF Core?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, рефлексия

Предположим есть моделька вида

```
public class CompanyServer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public int ServerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual Server Server { get; set; }
}
```

которая подключается к контексту через модель билдер

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyServer>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);

            entity.Property(e => e.CreateTime)
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                .HasDefaultValueSql(getdate);

            entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.CompanyId, e.ServerId })
                .IsUnique();

            entity
                .HasOne(d => d.Company)
                .WithMany(p => p.CompanyServer)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            entity
                .HasOne(d => d.Server)
                .WithMany(p => p.CompanyServer)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            entity.Property<DateTime>(lastUpdateKey)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
                .HasDefaultValueSql(getdate)
                .IsConcurrencyToken();
        });
```

Необходимо в метаданных контекста наити то место, где храниться связь между свойствами 'CompayId' и 'Company', а также 'ServerId' и 'Server'

EF Core ведь знает, что 'CompanyId' это айдишник из таблицы и по нему может загружать в свойство 'Company' эту таблицу.

В идеале, я бы хотел обратиться к метаданным передав свойство 'Company', а в ответ бы получил 'CompanyId'. И наоборот, обратиться бы к метаданным 'CompanyId', а в ответ получил бы связанное свойство 'Company'

где то тут должно быть 'EntityEntry', но где так и не допер

Answer (score 0):

Эта связь создается соглашением (Convention) [NavigationPropertyNameForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.navigationpropertynameforeignkeydiscoveryconvention(v=vs.113).aspx)

Если есть желание "вытащить" ее на свет из модели - вам надо создать свой DbModelBuilder, заполнить его в OnModelCreating, создать DbModel, достать из нее ConceptualModel, там найти AssociationType, в нем будет свойство Constraint типа  [ReferentialConstraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.metadata.edm.referentialconstraint(v=vs.110).aspx). В его свойствах уже будет вся нужная вам информация, но чтобы ее найти, придется заглянуть отладчиком в дочерние коллекции MetadataProperties и внимательно изучить их все.

"Из коробки" же EF умеет синхронизировать внешний ключ с навигационным свойством только в ограниченном числе случаев (таких как загрузка записи из БД или ее сохранение), в произвольный момент времени запустить этот процесс нельзя.

PS ссылки я давал на EF 6, но вряд ли в Core архитектура принципиально изменилась